# jpcap not printing out packets

Tags: java, jpcap

Trying to capture packets using jpcap.
However for some reason,my code will not print out packets.Only devices.
I don't understand why it's not working.

```
import jpcap.PacketReceiver;
import jpcap.JpcapCaptor;
import jpcap.NetworkInterface;
import jpcap.packet.Packet;
import jpcap.*;

public class JpcapTip implements PacketReceiver {
    public void receivePacket(Packet packet){
       System.out.println(packet);
      //  System.out.println(packet.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{
        NetworkInterface[] devices =  JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList();

        for (int i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(devices[i].description); // devices[0]

        }

        NetworkInterface deviceName = devices[0];

        JpcapCaptor  jpcap = JpcapCaptor.openDevice(devices[0], 1028, false, 1);
        jpcap.loopPacket(-1, new JpcapTip());

        //
   }
}
```

My compiler output.-

```
run:
Microsoft
Qualcomm Atheros Ar81xx series PCI-E Ethernet Controller
Microsoft
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: setRoutingOption
    at jpcap.JpcapCaptor.nativeOpenLive(Native Method)
    at jpcap.JpcapCaptor.openDevice(JpcapCaptor.java:68)
    at JpcapTip.main(JpcapTip.java:23)
```

Comment: Are you showing us all the code? In the console I see a `setRoutingOption` method throwing an error but I do not see it being called in your code...

Comment: Yes,100% sure.
http://i.imgur.com/pOgitEf.png

Comment: Hm. Weird. I'm not familiar with this library so there's not much I can do other than look at clues!

Comment: Ah,pity. This is for assignment and I've been stuck here for 2 days.